# How to name a java package in eclipse that complies with maven conventions but doesn't have main.java in the name?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

The issue is that I have a couple java packages in eclipse I need to export, they have to work with maven but cannot have the package name main.java.etc. I can't figure out how to make a package that is in the src/main/java/ directory without having main.java as the start of the package name.

Is there someway to export/make java packages in eclipse that don't have the name main.java in the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question isn't so much about naming as it is about compilation.  If you want to arrange your project source tree so that Java sources are under `src/main/java/`, then tell Eclipse that *that* is a source folder, and that `src/` itself isn't one.  Exactly how you do that may depend on your version of Eclipse, but explore the project properties.

Comment: I knew it was something simple like that, Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run the project without Main.java, click the down-arrow next to the Run button, click "Run Configurations" to open the Run Configurations dialog box, and click the new launch configuration button in the top-left corner of the left-hand pane. On the Main tab (the first one), enter the name of your Eclipse project for "Project" and "tester.Main" for "Main class". Then, insert @Example just before class Examples in your Examples class file.

Source: [http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs2102/b12/Assignments/making-packages.html#(part.*.For*.Eclipse)](http://source)

Comment: Sorry I meant the packages within a java project not the mvn package kind, I'll edit my post   
Edit: sorry misunderstood what you were talking about. What do you mean by using plugins instead of packages?

Comment: I think this link would help you http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs2102/b12/Assignments/making-packages.html#(part._.For_.Eclipse)